# Firebug collapses when a internal function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, firebug

The idea of script below is "preview" the content from a text area. How it works?

1. `$('#preview_post')` is an anchor that trigger the preview mode.
2. The textarea content is readed as `var content = $('#post_content').val();`
3. The form where the textarea reside is hidden in order to show the div (#content_previewed) where the markup will be showen.

This is the JS code:

```
var pl_previwing = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#preview_post').plPreviewPost();


});
jQuery.fn.plPreviewPost = function(options) {
    this.on('click', function(){
        var content = $('#post_content').val();
        $('#replay_container form').toggle(function(){
            pl_previwing = !pl_previwing;
        });
        console.log("previewing: " + pl_previwing);
        //plCallParser();
    });
};

function plCallParser(){
    if (pl_previwing){
        console.log("do a post here to process the markup");
    }
}
```

What's the problem here? If you note I have a commented line:

```
console.log("previewing: " + pl_previwing);
//plCallParser();
```

If I un-comment the line above, firebug will hang out abruptally and the browser freeze with the following message:

[image]

Translation:

> A script of this page can be busy, or could has stopped responding.
>   You might stop the script, or wait for a response.

### EDIT

- Current browser: 16.0.2, but it happens in all browsers
- The content of the textarea is not important, because it only have "test body"

Comment: Version of browser and Firebug? Anyway `log("do a post here to process the markup"); });` the closing `}` seems to be placed incorrectly here

Comment: how large is `parsed_content` ?

Comment: Where does `request` come from? Looks like a global.

Comment: @nhahtdh, it was just a typo

Comment: With Web Develpment Tools it appends an error: `too much recursion http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js Line 2`

Comment: Sorry for all: I forgot to clear the cache :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At:

```
function plCallParser() {
    if (pl_previwing) {
        console.log("do a post here to process the markup");
});
```

You need to put a "}; };" there, like so:

```
function plCallParser() {
    if (pl_previwing) {
        console.log("do a post here to process the markup");
    };
};
```

Just a simple error. I hate it when I mess up brackets.

Comment: Look the last comment of post